# create window group based on value of preceding row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like so:

```
#standardSQL
WITH k AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 subgrp, 'stuff1' content UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 'stuff2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3, 'stuff3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 4, 'stuff4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 1, 'ostuff1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2, 'ostuff2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 3, 'ostuff3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 4, 'ostuff4'
)
```

and like to group based on the `subgrp` value to re-create the missing `grp`: if `subgrp` value is smaller than previous row, belongs to same group.

Intermediate result would be:

```
| id | grp | subgrp | content |
| 1  |  1  |   1    | stuff1  |
| 2  |  1  |   2    | stuff2  |
| 3  |  1  |   3    | stuff3  |
| 4  |  1  |   4    | stuff4  |
| 5  |  2  |   1    | ostuff1 |
| 6  |  2  |   2    | ostuff2 |
| 7  |  2  |   3    | ostuff3 |
| 8  |  2  |   4    | ostuff4 |
```

on which I can then apply

```
SELECT id, grp, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(subgrp, content)) rcd
FROM k ORDER BY id, grp
```

to have I nice nested structure.

Notes:

- with 'id' ordered, subgrp is always in sequence so no `3` before `2`
- groups are not always `4` subgrp's - this is just to illustrate so cannot hardcode

Problem: how can I (re)create the `grp` column here ? I played with several Window functions to no avail.

**EDIT**

Although Gordon's answer work, it took **3min** over **104M** records to run and I had to remove an `ORDER BY` on the final resultset because of `Resources exceeded during execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. ORDER BY operator used too much memory.`

Anyone having an alternative solution for large dataset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to assign the group is to do a cumulative count of the `subgrp = 1` values:

```
select k.*,
       sum(case when subgrp = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
from k;
```

You can also do it your way, using `lag()` and a cumulative sum.  That requires a subquery:

```
select k.*,
       sum(case when prev_subgrp = subgrp then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as grp
from (select k.*,
             lag(subgrp) over (order by id) as prev_subgrp
      from k
     ) k
```

Comment: Thanks very much Gordon !! - actually I needed to add a `partition by` because the windowing had to be done within a higher dimension that I did not disclose. Before the `id`, consider `doc_nr` that includes these 8 lines.

Ended using the first cumulative count with: `sum(case when subgrp = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by doc_nr order by id) as grp`

Answer (score 0):

Below can potentially perform better - but has limitation - I assume there is no gaps in numbering within subgroups and respective ids

```
#standardSQL
WITH k AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 subgrp, 'stuff1' content UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 'stuff2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3, 'stuff3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 4, 'stuff4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 1, 'ostuff1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2, 'ostuff2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 3, 'ostuff3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 4, 'ostuff4'
)
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) grp,
  rcd
FROM (
  SELECT 
    MIN(id) id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(subgrp, content)) rcd  
  FROM k
  GROUP BY id - subgrp
)
```

result is

```
Row grp rcd.subgrp  rcd.content  
1   1   1           stuff1   
        2           stuff2   
        3           stuff3   
        4           stuff4   
2   2   1           ostuff1  
        2           ostuff2  
        3           ostuff3  
        4           ostuff4
```

Comment: Could not make work - The query could not be executed in the allotted memory.
Turned out using Gordon's answer, materializing the result and perform the  ORDER BY on the new table.

Comment: make sense, definitely this approach has number of limitations in addition to mentioned already no-gaps: query will be running out of memory if the arrays end up being too big, and row_number can also fail if there are too many groups.